# spyOn @react-native-firebase/analytics methods

Tags: jestjs, firebase-analytics

Basically, I want to make sure the methods of analytics are called with certain properties but so far it is not working:

```
Cannot spy the logAppOpen property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

the library is successfully mocked since I can see console log out of my jest.fn():

```
  jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/analytics', () => {
    return () => ({
      logAppOpen: jest.fn(() => console.log('mocked fun called')), //===>shown correctly
    })
  })
```

My class is:

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

export default class GA {
  appStarted = async () =>{
    console.log('appStarted called'); //==> showing
    await analytics().logAppOpen();
  }
}
```

my test:

```
it("should log app starting", async () =>{
    const spy = jest.spyOn(analytics, 'logAppOpen') //===>FAILS HERE
    congst ga = new GA();
    await ga.appStarted();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

but in my test: console.log(analytics) does show an empty object {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `analytics().logAppOpen()` while `jest.spyOn` tries to spy on `analytics.logAppOpen` which doesn't exist.

For lazily evaluated spied functions it's easier to expose them as variables:

```
const mockLogAppOpen = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/analytics', () => {
  return jest.fn()
  .mockReturnValue({ logAppOpen: mockLogAppOpen });
});
```

This way it can be accessed for call assertions. There's no need for `jest.spyOn` for a function that is already a spy.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. While it makes sense, that means it can't be placed in __mocks__ directory right? or i need to export mockLogAppOpen?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way for using `__mocks__` is to make mockLogAppOpen named export, `export const mockLogAppOpen = jest.fn(); export default jest.fn().mockReturnValue(...)`.

Comment: What exactly do you try? `__mocks__`, no `jest.mock` and  `expect(mockLogAppOpen).toHaveBeenCalled()` with mockLogAppOpen imported as `import { mockLogAppOpen } from ...`?